# Does it follow best-practice DB design to mix staff and customer details in 1 table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Users` which is currently holding data on both `Customers` and `Staff`. It has their names and emails and passwords etc. It also has a field called `TypeOfUserID` which holds a value to say what type of user they are .e.g Customer or Staff

Would it be better to have two separate tables: `Customers` and `Staff`?

It seems like duplication because the fields are the same for both types of user. The only field I can get rid of is the `TypeOfUserID` column.

However, having them both in one table called `Users` means that in my front-end application I have to keep adding a clause to check what type of user they are. If for any reason I need to allow a different type of user access e.g. `External Supplier` then I have to manage the addition of `TypeOfUserID` in multiple places in the WHERE clauses.

Comment: And what if a staff member is a customer too? You need to remove `TypeOfUserID` from the table, and assign a user to a role using a many to many table, something like `UserRoles`

Comment: That sort of depends. If staff members are just a special case of user, I don't see any reason you'd want to change anything about the database structure. Yes, for staff-specific stuff you'd need to be sure the person was staff, but I don't really see any way around that- you always have to know they're staff, first. If, however, you want finer-grained permissions than binary (and the change is easy to implement), you might want to change the database.

Comment: check this link regarding the inheritance pattern. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer:

It depends. If your current needs are met, and you don't foresee this model needing to be changed for a long time / it would be easy to change if you had to, stick with it.

## Longer answer:

If staff members are just a special case of user, I don't see any reason you'd want to change anything about the database structure. Yes, for staff-specific stuff you'd need to be sure the person was staff, but I don't really see any way around that- you always have to know they're staff, first.

If, however, you want finer-grained permissions than binary (a person can belong to the 'staff' group but that doesn't necessarily say whether or not they're in the users' group, for instance), you might want to change the database.

The easiest way to do that, of course, would be to have a unique ID associated with each user, and use that key to look up their group permissions in a different table.

Something like:

```
uid   | group
------------
1     | users
1     | staff
2     | users
3     | staff
4     | users
5     | admin
```

Although you may or may not want an actual string for each group; most likely you'd want another level of indirection by having a 'groups' table. So, that table above would be a
'group_membership' table, and it could look more like:

```
uid   | gid
------------
1     | 1
1     | 2
2     | 1
3     | 2
4     | 1
5     | 3
```

To go along with it, you'd have the 'groups' table, which would be:

```
gid  |  group
-------------
1    |  users
2    |  staff
3    |  admin
```

But, again, that's only if you're imagining a larger number of roles and you want more flexibility. If you only ever plan on having 'users' and 'staff' and staff are just highly privileged users, all of that extra stuff would be a waste of your time.

However, if you want really fine grained permissions, with maximum flexibility, you can use the above to make them happen via a 'permissions' table:

```
gid  | can_create_user | can_fire_people | can_ban_user
-------------------------------------------------------
1    | false           | false           | false
2    | true            | false           | true
3    | true            | true            | true
```

### Some Example Code

Here's a working PostgreSQL example of getting permissions `can_create_user` and `can_fire_people` for a user with uid 1:

```
SELECT bool_or(can_create_user) AS can_create_user,
       bool_or(can_fire_people) AS can_fire_people
FROM permissions
WHERE gid IN (SELECT gid FROM group_membership WHERE uid = 1);
```

Which would return:

```
can_create_user | can_fire_people 
----------------------------------
true            | false
```

because user 1 is in groups 1 and 2, and group 2 has the `can_create_user` permission, but
neither group has the `can_fire_people` permission.

((I know you're using SQL Server, but I only have access to a PostgreSQL server at the moment. Sorry about that. The difference should be minor, though.)

### Notes

You'll want to make sure that `uid` and `gid` are primary keys in the `users` and `groups` table, and that there are foreign key constraints for those values in every other table which uses them; you don't want nonexistent groups to have permissions, or nonexistent users to be accidentally added to groups.

## Alternatively

A graph database solves this problem pretty elegantly; you'd simply create edges linking users to groups, and edges linking groups to permissions. If you want to work with a technology that's currently sexy / buzzword compliant, might want to give that a try, depending on how enormous of a change that'd be.

## Further information

The phrase you'll want to google is "access control". You'll probably want to implement access control lists (as outlined above) or something similar. Since this is primarily a security-related topic, you might also want to ask this question on [sec.se](https://security.stackexchange.com), or at least look around there for related answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a seperate table for staff holding only `id` from the `user table` as the `foreign key`. If you do that, then any functionality related only to the staff member can query the `staff table` joining to the `user table`. This solution will also give you the fexibility for the future extension as any data releted only to the staff (for example department they work) member can be placed in the `staff table`.

Answer (score 0):

Even they look similar, they are logically from different areas. You will never need a union between those tables. But as your application develops, you will need to add more and more specific fields for these tables and they will became more different than similar.